# Paypal payment API error DoDirectPayment failed: (28)

Tags: paypal

My payment form has stopped working. I am using a Paypal API, and hosting the payment page on my site. However all of a sudden when someone tries to make a payment I am getting this error from Paypal

```
DoDirectPayment failed: (28)
```

None of the code seems to have changed, I have absolutely no idea what is causing this.

Comment: That is not a PayPal error message, so you'll have to dig deeper in debug logs to find an actual error from PayPal.

Comment: It is coming from the Paypal API.

Comment: No, it is coming from whatever you are calling. PayPal is not returning that error.